# For which $z$ goes $f(z) = e^{iz^2} \rightarrow 0$ if $|z| \rightarrow \infty$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the function:
$$f(z)  = e^{iz^2}.$$
For which values of $z$ goes $f(z) \rightarrow 0$ if $|z| \rightarrow \infty$.
I've read that it is possible if:
$$0 < arg(z) \leq \frac{\pi}{4}.$$

I've started by writing $f(z)$ as:
$$e^{iz^2} = e^{i|z|^2e^{i2\theta}}.$$
We can then write the power as:
$$i|z|^2e^{i2\theta} = i|z|^2cos(2\theta) - |z|^2sin(2\theta).$$
If $f(z)$ needs to go to zero, then the power of the exponent needs to be negative so:
$$sin(2\theta)> 0 $$
$$cos(2\theta)<0 $$

But then I get that $\theta \geq \frac{\pi}{4}$

Am I missing something or is there a better way to proof this.

Comment: Why the condition $\cos(2\theta)<0$? Which source for the solution?

Comment: if $cos(2\theta) < 0$ then $e^{i|z|^2 cos(2\theta}$ has a negative power so if $|z| \rightarrow \infty$ then the exponent will go to zero. And the source is mathematical methods for physics and engineers from Riley.

Comment: "then the exponent will go to zero" Sorry but you must be MUCH more precise here. Which exponent goes to zero?

Comment: Sorry for the miscommunication, but I mean $e^{i|z|^2cos(2\theta)} \rightarrow 0$ if $cos(2\theta) < 0$.

Comment: And this is not true since, for every real $|z|$ and $\theta$, $$|e^{i|z|^2\cos(2\theta)}|=1$$

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, but how can I find then the relation?

Comment: Easy: compute $$|e^{iz^2}|$$ for $$z=|z|\,e^{i\theta}$$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87369/discussion-between-belgium-physics-and-did).

Comment: Now I get that $sin(2\theta) > 0$ so this gives that the angle must be smaller than $\frac{\pi}{2}$, but this is not the needed relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z = x + iy$, then

$$ f(z) = e^{i(x+iy)^2} = e^{i(x^2-y^2+2ixy)} = e^{-2xy}e^{i(x^2-y^2)} $$

$|f| = e^{-2xy} \to 0$ if $xy > 0$, which means $z$ must be in the first or third quadrant, or $\arg(z) \in (0,\pi/2) \cup (-\pi/2,-\pi) $